# Android native "undeclared (first use in this function)"

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native-code

I am quite new to the android-ndk. 
For this code

```
const char *inCStr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, str, NULL);
if (inCSt && inCSt[0] != '\0') {
    char *outCStr = b64encode(inCStr);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, outCStr);
}
```

I get the error

```
'inCSt' undeclared (first use in this function)
if (inCSt && inCSt[0] != '\0') {
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
const char *inCStr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, str, NULL);
if (inCSt && inCSt[0] != '\0') {
```

You declared `inCStr` but tried to use `inCSt` without the `r`

Comment: Oh my god! Cannot believe it! It take me hours for research. Thank @Stratton